# Javascript filter function is returning the removed element and not the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

I am simply trying to remove an element from an array in javascript using the filter function. However, after running this function, `newArray` is an array with only 1 element - the one I removed.

I wanted an array with the original elements but minus the one I want to remove. How do I get that?

```
var newArray = comments.filter((comment) => comment.idComment == action.idSectionComments);
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Did you try inverting the condition in the filter?

Comment: There's nothing called `idComment` in your image also where's the `action` object and also it's better to post code instead images we couldn't rewrite you Objects to test it for you - what you said means that your condition isn't true maybe you need to replace `==` with `!=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not removing the element, you are picking it. The filter function return all elements in array that satisfy the condition, so you have to reverse the condition to filter all elements that doesn't match the id

```js
var newArray = comments.filter((comment) => comment.idComment !== action.idSectionComments);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var newArray = comments.filter((comment) => comment.idComment !== action.idSectionComments);
```